# Is it permitted to put the subject after a copula instead of before it?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, word-order, syntactic-analysis, hyperbaton

For instance, can one say “Smart is the Eastern system”?

Comment: It is permitted. But it's unusual; you shouldn't do this unless you have a reason to (like if you're writing poetry, or the exposition works better if you mention the copula first). If you do it often, people will think your writing is pretentious, or maybe that you're trying to be overly florid.

Comment: I can't think of any context in which writing *smart is the eastern system* would be better than *the eastern system is smart*.

Comment: Presumably you’re excluding interrogatives, where such an inversion is a requirement. How about in constructions like “So am I”?

Comment: An example of one construction people use inversion is *The Taj Mahal is one of the most beautiful buildings in the world. Equally beautiful, but much less well-known, is the ...* Here, inversion is used to put *beautiful* first, so as to smoothly connect the second sentence with the first one.

Comment: @PeterShor: Always with the value judgments. ^_^ How about “In the West we don’t do *smart*; *smart* is the Eastern system.”

Comment: @Robusto: that works fine, so I was wrong.

Comment: I meant this context: Smart is the Eastern system / And right is the custom of the elders. / They were born for a harem / Or for the unfreedom of a teremnon. (A. Pushkin)

Comment: @Anixx That’s a literary translation of some verse of Pushkin, and poetry is one of the places where you expect to find rhetorical devices in use. I’m not sure why the translator chose the full Greek term at the end rather than rhyming *harem* with *terem*. Perhaps they were avoiding the obvious rhyme for whatever reason, but few monoglot readers of English will know either Russian *терем* or its hypothesized Greek etymon *τέρεμνον*. The OED does attest *terem* as a Russian loanword, though.

Answer (score 2):

Given that **subject-copula-complement** is the usual ordering of elements for copular sentences in English, any deviation from that ordering is by definition unusual, including your **complement-copula-subject** ordering.

That does *not* make it ungrammatical. It makes it “sound funny”, makes it jump out dramatically from the more plodding and pedestrian text surrounding it. We call this rhetorical device ***anastrophe***, or sometimes ***hyperbaton*** in the modern sense of that word.

Figures of speech like these are seldom encountered in casual, spontaneous speech. You find them in poetry often enough, sometimes for the sake of the meter but other times for dramatic effect. For dramatic effect can they also be found amidst the polished prose of literature, oratory, or the Sunday sermon. Robert Louis Stevenson penned these lines:

> Home is the sailor, home from sea,
>   And the hunter home from the hill.

Examples aplenty of this can be found in (the more literary) English translations of the Bible, from *Blessed is he who comes in the name of the Lord* and *Blessed art thou among women* to the many repeated beatitudes like *Blessed are the peace-keepers...*

Such devices as these a non-native speaker should seldom if ever attempt in English. You should instead invest your time learning the usual way that ordinary people talk. The texts you are only now learning to compose should be free of rhetorical flourishes lest these be mistaken for unwitting blunders stemming from rank unfamiliarity with the expected norms of the English language.

Only after having taken full command of the English language should you even consider embarking on a study of its poetry, rhetoric, and literary techniques. Now is not the time for that.